# How to measure response size data for individual sampler during load test

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-plugins, beanshell

How to measure size of response data of multiple http samplers in JMeter. I need to find the individual size of all http sampler during the load, not for overall.
I am using Beanshell sampler but it is giving overall size not individual for each sampler.

```
import java.util.io.*;
import java.lang.io.*;
test = prev.getResponseDataAsString().length();
text = ctx.getCurrentSampler().getName();
log.info("Sampler Name: " +text+ ": Size: " +test);
if(text.equalsIgnoreCase("Test Sampler"))
{
 props.put("totalsize",Integer.parseInt("0"));
}
else
{
  props.put("totalsize", (props.get("totalsize")!=null?props.get("totalsize"):0) + test);
}
log.info("totalsize is = "+props.get("totalsize"));


I am using Beanshell sampler but it is giving overall size not individual for each sampler.
I need total individual response size for each sampler during my load test.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First of all I don't understand fully what your code is doing. You're using `props` shorthand for storing the data and the properties are **global** for the whole JVM so if you run your test with > 1 user the next thread will overwrite the value set by the previous thread. Maybe you should use `vars` instead which is for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) which are [thread-local](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage)?
2. I believe JMeter saves it into its [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) by default, take a look at `bytes` column which contains response size for each individual sampler.

   [image]
3. Also be aware that [starting from JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) mainly for performance reasons so consider migrating. More information: [Beanshell vs. JSR223 vs. Java For JMeter: Complete Showdown](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-jmeter)